# Is it possible to run Vagrant with Docker as provider AND provisioner?

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrant-provision

The Vagrant documentation describes how to start a VM that uses [Docker as provider](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html) as well as [how to provision a VM using Docker](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html). However, there is no information about whether it is possible to use both combined.

The reason why I would like to do this is because I am developing a Python web application which will be deployed via Docker anyway. It comes with some dependencies (system and Python libraries which are installed via a Dockerfile) as well as a Redis database that is running in another container.

If I could now create a Vagrant VM with Docker provider based on my Python/Webapp Dockerfile and provision this machine with further containers (e.g. Redis), then

- I would have a VM that is very fast to spin up and still mimics my deployment environment almost perfectly,
- I could use [PyCharm IDE's remote interpreter functionality](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html) to connect to the Python interpreter in this machine and benefit from code completion, debugging etc.

For this to work, one would probably need something like [Docker in Docker](https://blog.docker.com/tag/inception/) so that the Docker-based VM can spin up more containers via the Docker provisioner.

Is this approach possible in general or is there a working example available somewhere? Or if not, what could be a good alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: You want a VM that runs docker ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run Vagrant with Docker as provider AND provisioner?

Yes you can - I did not check with the latest vagrant version but this was working till vagrant 1.8.1

What you want basically is to spin a VM (running ubuntu or coreOS if you want to spin fast and running minimal) running multiple docker containers.

When you run the vagrant docker provider, you can still manage your own Vagrantfile.

so you need the main Vagrantfile (typically sitting as the root of your project)

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"
  end
  ...
end
```

and then in your `host/Vagrantfile` you would have something like

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Create and configure the VM(s)
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"

  # Spin up your own box (or one from Atlas)
  # and then provision it with Docker
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  ...
end
```

This is another typical `Vagrantfile` which points to the box that will be spinned (it can be ubuntu, centos, or coreOS if you want minimal OS) and it will provision docker (i.e. installing docker if its not installed on the box) so docker will be available from your VM.

ok so at this stage you have a VM with `docker` provider pointing to a VM which provision docker. Now you want to setup your 2 containers

In your main `Vagrantfile` you will add the 2 containers, something like

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host/Vagrantfile"
  end
  ...
  config.vm.define "python" do |python|
    python.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
      ...
      docker.image = "xxx"
      docker.ports = [80:80]
      docker.name = "python-system"
    end
  end
  config.vm.define "redis" do |redis|
    redis.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
      ...
      docker.image = "xxx"
      docker.ports = [80:80]
      docker.name = "redis"
    end
  end
end
```

This will spin up your 2 docker providers/containers python and redis.

Comment: why would someone get "docker preparing" problem while running "vagrant global-status"? problem is that I cannot even kill this process on windows 10.I do not want to reboot whole machine for this. I do not have to run "docker for windows" or kitematic such docker for windows tools right?